# How to add key shortcut in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

In TexStudio, "Preview Selection" can be done by the key shortcut "Alt P". But there is no key shortcut for "Clear Inline Preview". I'd like to know how to add a key shortcut for that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the menu `Options` -> `Configure TeXstudio`, there a tab named `Shortcuts`.

You may add almost any new Shortcut in the column named `Current Shortcut`. For example I personally added `Ctrl + Alt + N` and `Ctrl + Alt + T` to edit my tables a little bit faster while keeping them organized.

[image]

"Almost any" because you cannot (*should not*) duplicate shortcuts. You will receive a warning when trying it.

[image]

---

#### Edit

The "Clear Inline Preview" is in: `Idefix -> Clear Inline Preview`.
Basically, every single command accessed by menus is displayed at the position in the `Shortcut`s options.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question. How do you set the Alt key in setting shortcut? When I type Shift +A, it will only display Shift + ....

Comment: @hermes, you just need to press the combination you want, `Alt + a`, or `Alt + Shift + a`. Please, notice that `Shift + a` triggers a warning, since this is the standard key combination for `A`.